# Scratch orgs are created with Russian language for Ukrainian and other Eastern European Dev Hubs even if Dev Hub language is English

Tags: scratch-org, language, scratch-org-definition-file, dev-hub

Why scratch orgs are created with Russian language for Ukrainian and other Eastern European Dev Hubs even if Dev Hub language is English?

This happens for Ukrainian, Lithuanian and other Eastern European Dev Hubs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue.

There is a Github Issue Link https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1962

And Known Issue link https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000smIKf/scratch-orgs-created-in-russian-language-even-if-devhub-org-has-been-set-with-english-language

Workaround is to specify the "language": "en_US" in the definition file to create the scratch org in the English language.